# External integration: MuleSoft vs Salesforce Connect?

Tags: integration, lightning-connect, odata, mulesoft

I am looking to integrate an external system that supports OData into SFDC. Both ends of this integration will need to have read and write access to each other. I am assuming a peak traffic rate of 10,000 reads and 10,000 writes per hour with a maximum of 200,000 each per day.

So far I see 2 options:

1. Native SFDC solution

   - Use Salesforce/Lightning Connect to facilitate reads/writes by SFDC
   - Write custom web services to enable the external system to read/write to/from SFDC
2. Third party solution (the MuleSoft Salesforce Connector)

I am looking for reasons as to why the MuleSoft Salesforce Connector might be the better choice here -or not.